# Swift framework how to run and test

Tags: ios, swift, ios-frameworks

I want to build a swift framework which can be added to hosting applications and run some logic

It basically show a new screen with web view which does some things (among other JS bridging)

After creating the logic as a regular app (with invocation button) i am now trying to convert it to a framework which can be added easily to existing projects

Is this the right way to do it? my code contain a ViewController which should be segue to

How do i start converting it to a framework? can a framework contain ViewControllers? how to test it? I see for example that a regular UIView dont exist is not available in the view adder